# how to output the value?

Tags: php

```
$i = 1;
 foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
     $values = $o->getValues();
     foreach ($values as $v) {
            print_r($v->getData());
     }
     $i++;
 }
```

The above code outputs the following result:

```
Array
(
    [option_type_id] => 9
    [option_id] => 3
    [sku] => 
    [sort_order] => 0
    [default_title] => Black
    [store_title] => 
    [title] => Black
    [default_price] => 0.0000
    [default_price_type] => fixed
    [store_price] => 
    [store_price_type] => 
    [price] => 0.0000
    [price_type] => fixed
)
Array
(
    [option_type_id] => 7
    [option_id] => 3
    [sku] => 
    [sort_order] => 0
    [default_title] => Red
    [store_title] => 
    [title] => Red
    [default_price] => 0.0000
    [default_price_type] => fixed
    [store_price] => 
    [store_price_type] => 
    [price] => 0.0000
    [price_type] => fixed
)
Array
(
    [option_type_id] => 8
    [option_id] => 3
    [sku] => 
    [sort_order] => 0
    [default_title] => White
    [store_title] => 
    [title] => White
    [default_price] => 0.0000
    [default_price_type] => fixed
    [store_price] => 
    [store_price_type] => 
    [price] => 0.0000
    [price_type] => fixed
)
```

I want to output the `[title]` value. How do I do that? Thank you. I've tried to use `$v->getData()['title']`, but it did not work.

Comment: Bit of redundancy in the final paragraph there.  If it doesn't work, does it return anything, even an error?  If so, what is the output?

Comment: Why did you paste the same sentence like 10 times over and over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before php5.4, you can't do `$v->getData()['title']`, you need use a variable.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
    $values = $o->getValues();
    foreach ($values as $v) {
        $data = $v->getData();
        echo $data['title'];
    }
    $i++;
}
```